# ionic storage module giving OpaqueToken error with angular 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, ionic-native, ionic-storage

I have updated my ionic project to angular 5 and i got the below error with many ionic native plugins..

> angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken

Resolved all of the issues after updating to the latest version , except for ionic-storage.
Still its giving this error

> node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.d.ts import { OpaqueToken }
>   from '@angular/core';

```
node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
```

We can see one open issue @github ([142](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/issues/142)) but no fix or workaround found.

Comment: Hmm, I am using Angular 5.51. Got no problem installing storage module just now. Try to remove the plugin and install the latest version, hope this will help!

Comment: Using cordova-android 7.1.x(latest)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this issue by upgrading `@ionic/storage` to version `2.1.2` or higher.

**Update (context):**

`OpaqueToken` was removed in Angular v5 (it's been [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01) since 
Angular v4). The corresponding change in the `@ionic/storage` package was done in [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/commit/1d9149de404726c5d3c3483d1b463c06695e009c#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2) change as part of the `2.1.2` update.

Comment: Can you explain why upgrading would solve the issue? Is there a known bug, that you can link to?

Comment: @MunimMunna Exactly why do you think this is not an answer? Because it is. It could have used some background or explanation, but it is an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this may be an answer, but looks like a direction with no context or assurance. Only way to find out is upgrading something you may even don't need to, not appreciated at all! And this one liner could fit really well in a comment.

Comment: @MunimMunna apologies for not being thorough in my answer, I've added some context to my original post.

Comment: Now this is an answer, even me who has no idea of Angular 5 understand it.

Comment: @MunimMunna Sure, but that would warrant a downvote, not deletion. As it (attempts to) answer the question. Comments are for requests for clarification or remarks tangential to the problem. Comments are not for answers.